# Overload a function created by returning it to capture static variables

Tags: typescript

I've a function similar to this one:

```
export const foo = function () {
    const myObject = new MyObject();
    return function foo(param1?: number, param2?: string): void{
        ...
    };
}();
```

Where `myObject` is a variable a use as a temp inside the function, and I capture it this way to avoid allocating it every time.

I wanted to overload it to create 2 different versions:

```
export function foo(): void;
export function foo(param1: number): void;
```

It's not important that this overload makes sense, it's just an example.

I wanted to understand if there is a way to overload `foo` declared that way, or I have to put the "static" variable `myObject` as a module variable.
I would like to keep it "local" to the function if possible, but couldn't find a way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only write overloads on a regular `function` declaration, so just write the `function` declaration and the `return` clause separately, like this:

```
export const foo = function () {
    const myObject = new MyObject();

    function foo(num: number): number
    function foo(str: string): string;
    function foo(numOrString: number | string): number | string {
        return numOrString;
    };

    return foo;
}();
```